# If I need to do a course reversal before initiating an approach, do I need to notify ATC that I'm doing it?

Tags: air-traffic-control, instrument-flight-rules, approach

If I need to do a course reversal before initiating an approach, do I need to notify ATC that I'm going to do the course reversal, or is it implied that I'm going to do it?

For example:

[image: SLVR VOR Z 16]

If I'm approaching the VIR VOR with a course of 230, I would need to do a course reversal to get established on the outbound course. Should I notify ATC that I'm going to do the course reversal?

Comment: Why would you do a course reversal? Wouldn't you just turn prior to the IAF to intercept the outbound course?

Comment: Which country or regulator are you asking about? Bolivia?

Comment: @JonathanWalters Because ICAO states the following about base turns: "Unless the procedure specifies particular entry restrictions, reversal procedures shall be entered from a
track within ±30° of the outbound track of the reversal procedure. However, for base turns, where the ±30° direct entry
sector does not include the reciprocal of the inbound track, the entry sector is expanded to include it." So with a course of 230 I would be outside of the "entry sector" for the base turn.

Comment: @Pondlife Yes, Bolivia.

Comment: If in doubt, it's better to advice ATC one time too many.

Comment: @Luis Eduardo Vaca, I would expect a racetrack followed by a base turn, with the racetrack getting you into an entry sector.  The implication is that you have to do the course reversal, and therefore do not report it, but the requirement is that you do a racetrack to setup for the entry sector. Does that address your concern?

Comment: @J.Hougaard: agree completely. When uncertain, tell ATC. Only once have I had ATC complain, slightly, when I told them I was executing a (charted) course reversal maneuver. Otherwise, ATC has simply acknowledged my transmission. (This is in the U.S.)

Comment: @mongo Yes it does, however like J.Hougaar said it's better to just tell them that I'm doing it, specially since we have no radar service here.

Comment: Suggesting "tell ATC anyway" doesn't answer the question.  He's. It asking for advice but for facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is implied.

When you are cleared for the approach you are cleared for the procedure turn, or base turn as indicated on the plate.  Since your current heading puts you outside the entry sector, you do a racetrack to get aligned with the entry to the base turn.

It is always good to know when you have to call and when you don't because there could be heavy traffic, high workload, or who knows what. But if we're talking a competency ride or something like that, you should know whether you need to make the call or not.  All that said, one can of course report the course reversal if there is doubt.

In this instance, there is no requirement to report the turn.